# Simple postgres query but performing very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a following query

```
explain analyze 
SELECT "booked_rooms".* 
FROM "booked_rooms" 
INNER JOIN "bookings" 
    ON "bookings"."id" = "booked_rooms"."booking_id" 
WHERE (booked_rooms.arrival_date <= '2022-08-01' 
AND booked_rooms.departure_date >= '2022-07-01') 
AND "booked_rooms"."hotel_id" = 935 
AND "bookings"."status" IN ('confirmed', 'modified')
```

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                     |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Gather  (cost=1134.98..12664.78 rows=2714 width=407) (actual time=1.453..13.914 rows=1784 loops=1)                                                                             |
|   Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                           |
|   Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                          |
|   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=134.98..11393.38 rows=1131 width=407) (actual time=0.416..5.306 rows=595 loops=3)                                                                     |
|         ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on booked_rooms  (cost=134.89..6080.30 rows=1458 width=407) (actual time=0.371..2.046 rows=675 loops=3)                                  |
|               Recheck Cond: ((hotel_id = 935) AND (arrival_date <= '2022-08-01'::date) AND (departure_date >= '2022-07-01'::date))                                             |
|               Heap Blocks: exact=714                                                                                                                                           |
|               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_booked_rooms_on_hotel_id_arrival_departure_date  (cost=0.00..134.72 rows=3499 width=0) (actual time=0.862..0.862 rows=2024 loops=1) |
|                     Index Cond: ((hotel_id = 935) AND (arrival_date <= '2022-08-01'::date) AND (departure_date >= '2022-07-01'::date))                                         |
|         ->  Index Scan using bookings_pkey on bookings  (cost=0.09..3.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=2024)                                          |
|               Index Cond: (id = booked_rooms.booking_id)                                                                                                                       |
|               Filter: ((status)::text = ANY ('{confirmed,modified}'::text[]))                                                                                                  |
|               Rows Removed by Filter: 0                                                                                                                                        |
| Planning Time: 0.431 ms                                                                                                                                                        |
| Execution Time: 14.080 ms                                                                                                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
EXPLAIN 15
Time: 0.097s
```

Index definitions:

- On booked_rooms `"idx_booked_rooms_on_hotel_id_arrival_departure_date" btree (hotel_id, arrival_date, departure_date)`
- On bookings `"bookings_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)` AND `"index_bookings_on_status" btree (status)`

Regarding the number of data on both tables:

```
booked_rooms  bookings
+---------+  +---------+  
| count   |  | count   |  
|---------|  |---------|
| 2226614 |  | 1958549 |
+---------+  +---------+
```

The query seems to be quite slow as when I run it it takes ~1.5sec.

I don't understand why the `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan` is happening before the Index Cond that does the same condition. Seems that too much time goes on the bitmap heap scan?

If anyone have some advice here how to speed up the query, I would appreciate?

Update:

With increasing the date range for the same `hotel_id`

```
explain analyze SELECT "booked_rooms".* FROM "booked_rooms" INNER JOIN "bookings" ON "bookings"."id" = "booked_rooms"."b
 ooking_id" WHERE "booked_rooms"."hotel_id" = 935 AND "bookings"."status" IN ('confirmed', 'modified') AND (booked_rooms.arrival_date <= '2022-10-01' A
 ND booked_rooms.departure_date >= '2022-05-01')
```

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                          >
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
| Gather  (cost=1156.54..20006.21 rows=4732 width=407) (actual time=3.550..37.854 rows=4074 loops=1)                                                  >
|   Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                >
|   Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                               >
|   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=156.54..18533.01 rows=1972 width=407) (actual time=1.122..12.234 rows=1358 loops=3)                                        >
|         ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on booked_rooms  (cost=156.45..9851.57 rows=2542 width=407) (actual time=1.035..4.323 rows=1657 loops=3)      >
|               Recheck Cond: ((hotel_id = 935) AND (arrival_date <= '2022-10-01'::date) AND (departure_date >= '2022-05-01'::date))                  >
|               Heap Blocks: exact=2462                                                                                                               >
|               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_booked_rooms_on_hotel_id_arrival_departure_date  (cost=0.00..156.15 rows=6101 width=0) (actual time=2.504>
|                     Index Cond: ((hotel_id = 935) AND (arrival_date <= '2022-10-01'::date) AND (departure_date >= '2022-05-01'::date))              >
|         ->  Index Scan using bookings_pkey on bookings  (cost=0.09..3.42 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=4971)               >
|               Index Cond: (id = booked_rooms.booking_id)                                                                                            >
|               Filter: ((status)::text = ANY ('{confirmed,modified}'::text[]))                                                                       >
|               Rows Removed by Filter: 0                                                                                                             >
| Planning Time: 0.385 ms                                                                                                                             >
| Execution Time: 38.190 ms                                                                                                                           >
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
EXPLAIN 15
Time: 0.124s
```

Comment: Execution Time: 14.080 ms, that’s just 14 milliseconds. Could you share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this query? And if possible, using different values for the hotel id and the dates

Comment: But seems that execution time is not relevant as when I run the query it takes ~1.9sec... Regarding execution time, seems it's my mistake as I read it as `14 sec` instead of `15 miliseconds` :(

Comment: I've updated for bigger time range

Comment: Again lightning fast:  Execution Time: 38.190 ms. That’s 38 milliseconds. Processing the results are in your application might be slow, but than you have to check network latency and the application. There is not much to improve within the database, even when you (could) reduce the execution time to zero, you would stil hit the 1.9 seconds that you measured somewhere

Comment: I see now. Well I'm querying it using psql, so not sure what might slowing down it but you're right. Thank you a lot! Cheers

Comment: Maybe it is fast upon repeat execution because the data it needs is already in memory, or maybe the time is spent sending 4000 rows over the network/IPC and then formatting it on the client.

Comment: I am not seeing anywhere that it is taking 1.9 seconds. The highest value I see(from \timing I assume) is 0.124 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps high network latency is part of the problem.